# How to cast a base class to a derived class

Tags: c#

Why can't I cast a base class to a derived class? Also, why doesn't the compiler catch this?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Parent p = new Parent();
            Child c = (Child)p;

        }
    }

    class Parent
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    class Child : Parent
    {
        public string OtherDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretend it works. What does `c.OtherDate` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is an instance of `Parent`, so you cannot tell the runtime to interpret it as one.

The compiler does not catch it because code like this

```
 Parent p = new Child();
 Child c = (Child)p;
```

and compilers do not do the static code analysis needed to catch it. Reasons for not checking it are:

- It is time consuming
- It can only catch some of the instances of the error.